# revoking a previously set user id from google analytics gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

in this google analytics gtag.js document:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id

i see that to set a user id i need to add the following to my code:

```
gtag('set', {'user_id': 'USER_ID'});
```

my question is, what do i need to do to revoke this?

lets say i have a login functionality. so when a user logs-in i want to set his id in gtag, but when he logs-out i want gtag to forget his id.

of course an obvious answer would be to just set a new user_id with some random guid, but is there an official gtag.js way to do this?